# Mutated array while being enumerated

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

The error I am getting is

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <CALayerArray: 0x7c85080> was mutated while being enumerated.'
```

What I understand from `NSGenericException` is that I am removing something from my array while it is enumerating. Still knowing that and looking around I can not seem to resolve my issue. Here is the code below.

```
-(void)tableView(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
     //Checks if message has been read. If message has not it updates the unreadMessages array
     if ([unreadMessage containsObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"m%@",[[storage_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"id"]]] == TRUE && [[[storage_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"itemtype"] isEqualToString:@"message"]  == TRUE){

     //Unread
     [unreadMessage removeObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"m%@",[[storage_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"id"]]];
     [unreadMessage writeToFile:[self saveUnreadMessages] atomically:YES];
     //Read
     [readMessage addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"m%@",[[storage_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"id"]]];
     [readMessage writeToFile:[self saveReadMessages] atomically:YES];
     [tableView reloadData];
 }
 else if ([unreadNewsletter containsObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"n%@",[[storage_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"id"]]] == TRUE && [[[storage_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"itemtype"] isEqualToString:@"newsletter"]  == TRUE){

     //Unread
     [unreadNewsletter removeObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"n%@",[[storage_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"id"]]];
     [unreadNewsletter writeToFile:[self saveUnreadNewsletters] atomically:YES];
     //Read
     [readNewsletter addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"n%@",[[storage_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"id"]]];
     [readNewsletter writeToFile:[self saveReadNewsletters] atomically:YES];
     [tableView reloadData];
 }
}
```

Comment: I'm sure you're doing it in a `for(... in ...)` loop. You can't do it.

Comment: Can you provide more context on where this code is being executed? The array being mutated is a CALayerArray, which hints me toward some UI updates; and I don't see any of that except the tableView reload. Where is this code happening?

Comment: This code is happening in my `-(void)tableView(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Comment: Thank you to @ctrahey who actually got the answer. I had a NSThread in my viewDidAppear that was detaching from the main thread. After looking up some more info I changed it to the main thread and all is well. The CALayerArray was the thing that tipped me off. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't modify the array you are iterating over. If you intent to do so, you should iterate over a copy of it:

```
for (id item in [array copy])
{
    …
}
```

(with ARC. `[[array copy] autorelease]` without ARC.)

If needed, you can check if the item is still in the mutable array before doing anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could build up a new NSMutableArray of the objects needing to be removed while iterating through your original mutable array and then, after the loop completes, call

```
[originalMutableArray removeObjects:newArrayContainingObjectsNeedingToBeRemoved];
```